# How to find GIT on a Macbook Pro 5 ver 10.6.8

Tags: macos, git

I have downloaded and installed GIT on my Macbook, but I cannot find it in order to run it. (I am complete beginner with GIT and am using it for an assignment).

I have gone to the terminal and typed "which Git" and get back /usr/local/bin/Git.
How do I get here. When I type /usr/local/bin/Git in the terminal it says illegal instruction.

I have gone to Applications in windows, but do not see a Git executable and also checked in Utilities in Applications. The only GIT file I see is the install package on my hard drive, but after I install (which it does perfectly) I cannot find this or run it.

Comment: From where did you download it and what steps did you perform to install it?

Answer (score 0):

If the file system that you use is case-sensitive, you should type all commands as they written: **git** (no capital **G**)

Type `/usr/local/bin/git`

PS in my case FS is not case-sensitive: [image])

Comment: Many thanks for your help and comment. I upgraded my OS X to El Capitan and this seemed to do the trick.